# Show loader while waiting for servlet to forward to next page

Tags: jsp, servlets, loader, forward

I have an index.html where I have a form. When I press submit that form does a POST request to my servlet. This servlet does some heavy things and then forwards to a jsp. What I want is when I press submit, to show a loader.
I know how to do this via javascript (preventDefault etc). I don't want that. Can this be accomplished by the servlet? I was trying to output a "page" that contains only the loader, and then do the heavy stuff, and in the end forward to a jsp. That didn't work. For some reason it doesn't even leave the index.html, just stays there until the servlet is finished, and in the end I get forwarded to the jsp.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Format the question so that it will be more readable.

Comment: You need a progress bar..That can only happen if you employ Ajax for the POST. Otherwise, the browser will not perform any animation while the servlet is processing.

Comment: Refer this : http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/06/11/jsp_progressbars.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can only be accomplished using AJAX.

So, on the click of the submit button, display the Loading image, and make the ajax call to the servlet. So while the servlet will be processing, the loading image will be displayed. Uppon returning from ajax call, you can use javascript to do any actions you require (forward user to another page / show errors .. etc).

I highly recommend you to see [JQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (this is the most easy and effective script I have ever used)

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/myServlet',
    data: {
        name: $('#name').val()
    },
    beforeSend:function(){
        // this is where we append a loading image
    },
    success:function(data){
        // successful request; do something with the data            
    },
    error:function(){
        // failed request; give feedback to user
    }
});
```

Comment: what if i press refresh button while the loading image is being displayed. the code in my servlet will be reloaded???

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Ajax`.. 
on `form submit` make a `ajax call` to `servlet` which will return the `things` / `html` nedded to show `loading` page. you can use that returned `page` to replace the `form` or anything in `current page`.

after `ajax` `form submission` will continue as ususal... when other `Servlet` finishes the `processing` you will be redirected to `result page`.

Comment: @alkis in Question you `never said anything related to ajax`. You said about `prevent defualt`.
Also `One Request` can have at any given time only `1 response`. If you try to `commit/send response multiple time` you will get `ResponseAlreadyCommited exception`

Comment: @rahul maindargi is right on that. You never said anything about ajax. And this you are trying to do is only doable with ajax btw....

Comment: I said javascript. I meant ajax, but my bad, I should have been specific.